# Deployment of Node native modules to Azure WebSites,I'm experiencing some problems

Tags: node.js, azure, opencv, azure-web-app-service, node-modules

- I deploy a node application to the Azure website.
- The tricky part is that I'm using a node module called "opencv" that needs to be compiled at install time using node-gyp.
- I use the `node-gyp rebuild --arch=ia32` command to compile it int the windows10. But when I used it in the Azure website， I get following problem:

> ```
> Wed Apr 26 2017 04:48:35 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
>
> Error: The specified module could not be found.
>
> \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\api\lib\opencv.node
>
> at Error (native)
> at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
> at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\api\lib\image_operation.js:5:14)
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
> ```

This is the code I call：

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var opencv = require("./opencv.node");

function isContains(str, substr) {
    return new RegExp(substr).test(str);
}

module.exports = {
    post: function (imageInfo, data) {
        if (isContains(imageInfo.imageName, ".yuv")) {
            var imageName = imageInfo.imageName.substr(0, imageInfo.imageName.length - 3) + "jpg";
            opencv.yuvToJpeg(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../image/" + imageName), imageInfo.width, imageInfo.height, Array.prototype.slice.call(data, 0));
        } else if (isContains(imageInfo.imageName, ".jpg")) {
            fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../image/" + imageInfo.imageName), data);
    }
            return "success";
    }
};
```

But that file is in-fact deployed on the server:

Please help me, and tell me what to do

Answer (score 0):

Its [readme](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) says that *"You'll need OpenCV 2.3.1 or newer installed before installing node-opencv"*. And as Azure Web Apps is a Software as a service (SaaS), we don't have the privilege to install arbitrary software there. But if that is a requirement for you, you'll need to use an alternative offering, like Cloud Service or VM.